# Is a multi-demionsional array the same as a matrix?

Tags: c++, graphics

I understand what an array and a matrix is. I want to learn how to create 3D graphics and I want to know if a multi-demionsional array is the same as a matrix.

Comment: What does "the same" mean? What is a "matrix", and how would you recognise it if you saw it in the street?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several uses of the term "matrix". Normally however we say that a matrix is a 2-dimensional array of scalar (integer or floating point) values, with known dimensions, an entry for every position (no missing values allowed), and arranged such that the columns represent observations about or operations on the rows of another matrix. So if we have a matrix with four columns, it only makes sense if we have another matrix or vector with  four rows to which the four columns apply.

So the obvious way to represent a matrix in C++ is as a 2D array. But 2D arrays aren't identical with matrices. You might have a 2D array that is not a matrix (missing values which are uninitialised or nan), or a matrix that is not a 2D array (we could represent as a 1D array and do the index calculations manually, or as a "sparse matrix"  where most values are expected to be zero and we just have a list of non-zero values).

Answer (score 1):

Matrix is an abstract mathematical concept that can be modeled in C++ using a number of ways:

- A two-dimensional array,
- An array of pointers to arrays with arrays of identical size
- A `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`
- An `std::array<N,std::array<M,T>>`
- A library-specific opaque implementation

The actual implementation is always specific to the drawing library that you have in mind.